# Stickiness based on some request attribute instead of session in Iplanet server

Tags: java, webserver, weblogic, application-server, iplanet

We are using Iplanet web server an weblogic cluster as the application server in our project. Currently, we are using session based stickiness which makes sure the request from the same session goes to the same weblogic node. But because of this we have some issues in our application. We don't want our session to be sticky with one node rather we want to configure it in a way so that the stickiness can be provided based on request attribute. E.g.

Our application loads data for an organization and then caches it in memory. Now when user logs out and log back in again, the user might go to different node and then the application again goes to DB and loads the data which causes an un-necessary call to DB. To resolve this issue, we want to make sure that the request from same organization goes to the same node only in subsequent logins.

Comment: where you are storing data at client or server ??

Answer (score 0):

Can you please go through the below URK, you will get information.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15357_01/coh.360/e15831/activecache.htm.

Raja

Comment: I don't want to cache the sessions. Instead I want to drive my stickiness based on the cached data.

Comment: @mittalpraveen Ever considered using cookies? Cause with that you can ensure association of a given client to particular node while sending request to your server.